# Untraceable Exceptions in Windows.Forms Application.Run()

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2008, exception

I have an old Windows.Forms Application that I am trying to debug.

Sometimes after running a few minutes it will produce an ArithmeticException or an OverflowException. The source must be somewhere in the codebase, but the stacktrace always points to the line `Application.Run(mainForm);`

The StackTrace is useless as it only shows Windows.Forms native calls:

```
 bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   bei Program.Main() in C:\xy\Program.cs:Zeile 102.
```

To find the source of the exception I have added an exception handler to
`System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException` and to `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

I have tried enabling and disabling catching exceptions with
`System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode();`

The ThreadException event handler is never called. The UnhandledException event handler just reports the same exception I see in Visual Studio.

In Visual Studio I have enabled breaking execution when an exception is thrown:
[image]
This had no effect whatsoever.

What can I do to find the offending line of code?

---

edit: the full exception details:

[image]

---

If I start the process without any debugger attached, and wait for it to crash before attaching a debugger, I get the following exception:

```
Unbehandelte Ausnahme bei 0x0c9f9e1b in program.exe: 0xC0000090: Floating-point invalid operation.
```

Debugging then leads to this piece of disassembly

```
0C9F9E12  add         esi,10h 
0C9F9E15  push        0CA1FD48h 
0C9F9E1A  push        eax  
0C9F9E1B  fmul        qword ptr ds:[0CA202E0h] 
0C9F9E21  fstp        dword ptr [esp+18h]
```

I cannot parse this, but I suspect this is merely the DispatchMessageW function

Comment: Can you step through the code one line at a time to determine where this is occurring at?  You might also try adding assertions using the `Debug` class at locations throughout the code to try to narrow down where the exception could be.

Comment: I am currently trying to step through the code, but the problem is that it is a large codebase using multiple threads, and the exception only happens after some time.

Comment: Are you sure the exception has no information? Look at `InnerException`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that information. The InnerException is null, I'll post the full Exception

Comment: Did you modify VS settings for debugging? Uncheck "Unwind the callstack..." ("Aufrufliste für unbehandelte Ausnahmen entladen" - what a misleading translation).

Comment: That setting was checked, but unchecking it did not change the resulting exception (same stack trace, same missing InnerException)

Comment: Try this: Start the app withut debugging (ctrl-f5). Then attach to the process in native mode (Tools->Attach). Check the exception settings and wait for the exception to come. Maybe this low level debugging mode can catch it.

Comment: Unfortunately the resulting exception is exactly the same. If I do not attach a debugger at all until the crash, and only attach if afterwards, I get a Floating-point invalid operation, and some assembly code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The diagnostic here is that you have legacy unmanaged code in your process, judging from the call stack you posted that's likely to be an old ActiveX control.

These exceptions are hardware exceptions generated by the FPU, the floating point processor.  Which can be put in an operation mode where it reports problems by raising exceptions, like the STATUS_FLOAT_OVERFLOW and STATUS_FLOAT_INVALID_OPERATION exceptions that you are seeing.  Instead of generating infinity, NaN or denormals.  The FMUL instruction can easily generate such an exception.

Software that changes the FPU operation mode is pretty fundamentally incompatible with managed code.  Which requires that FPU exceptions are always masked.  Masking these exceptions is entirely normal and what is done with all modern software.  Back in the previous century these exceptions were however considered an asset to diagnose floating point calculations going haywire.  In particular, old Borland runtime libraries unmasked these exceptions.

Well, this is all rather bad news in case you didn't get that message yet.  First place to look is to try to diagnose why this code is throwing floating point exceptions.  Bad data tends to be the most common reason.  Secondly, you *really* have to do something about the FPU control register being changed, this can easily cause managed code to fail as well.  Particularly a problem in WPF code, it likes using NaN.

Finding such code is pretty easy with the debugger.  Use the Debug + Windows + Registers debugger window.  Right-click the window and tick the "Floating point" option.  The value of the CTRL register is crucial, it should be `027F` in a managed program.  Step through the program, coarse at first, you found the trouble-maker when the register changes.  If it is 64-bit program then also tick "SSE", the MXCSR register should be `00001F80`.

You cannot directly reset the FPU control register with managed code but you can use a trick.  The CLR resets it whenever it handles an exception.  So a *possible* fix is to intentionally throw and catch an exception, after the statement that caused the control register value to change:

```
        try {  throw new Exception("Resetting FPU control register, please ignore"); }
        catch { }
```

Pinvoking the _controlfp() function in msvcrt.dll is a more direct way.  But of course with the side-effect of both that now that library is operating in a mode that it wasn't designed for, it of course won't expect to encounter Nan and Infinity values.  Long term, you really need to consider retiring that old component or library.

Comment: Thank you! This saved me days of further fruitless debugging! This indeed appears to be the problem. There are several c/c++ libraries and a 3d viewer app in this program, one of them must be responsible. I have not yet found the definite source of the problem, but I am now able to track it down by littering the code with `double d = 0; d=d/d;` and catching and logging the resulting ArithmeticException.

Comment: Thanks for the great, comprehensible explanation. We encounter this problem regularly in WPF and have patched in calls to _fpreset() before many WPF operations, but the kicker is that we're using the managed System.Data.Odbc classes. These classes use the native ODBC library and drivers under the covers and some of those appear to wreck the FPU state. It seems like the managed ODBC interface layer should reset the floating point state after each native ODBC operation so the function caller doesn't have to worry about it.