# WPF SetParent throwing an ArithmeticException

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, user32, setparent

I have been developing an add on with C# and WPF to an application.

It's been working fine until launched on a Win7 machine. The symptoms are that a Microsoft .NET Framwork's "Unhandled exception" dialog pops up on startup for *System.ArithmeticException* (Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation) and gives a stack trace pointing to `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track.ComputeScrollBarLengths (...)` and deeper.

So, I began to debug the app: it showed that System.ArithmeticException was thrown when setParent from user32.dll was called. This is done when the application makes a call to show the add-on UI.

```
public bool ShowUI(int Parent)
{
userControl = new MyUserControl(); // Extends System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
SetParent(userControl.Handle, new IntPtr(Parent)); // <- exception thrown here
...
}
```

What would possibly be causing this issue?

Comment: This exception is invariably caused by unmanaged code changing the floating point processor control register.  WPF has a rock hard requirement that this never happens, floating point exceptions need to stay disabled.  Chase it down with the debugging tips in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14466004/17034).

Comment: Thanks. Apparently it is something related to it, since calling `_fpreset()` from msvcrt.dll in the add-on's bootstrapper seems to resolve this issue by now. It needs further testing, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding the solution here in case someone finds it userful.

Something in the unmanaged code – only in the 64-bit version, though – caused the floating point operations to cause exceptions which caused this error, as mentioned in Hans Passant's comment. The solution was something similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19722292/8063451

Adding the `_fpreset()` function call at the initialisation of my add-on solved the problem.

```
    [DllImport("msvcr.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int _fpreset();

    public static void Run()
    {
       // Other code
        _fpreset(); // Reinitialises the floating-point package
    }
```