# Why am I getting the System.OverflowException?

Tags: c#, integer-overflow

This program is coded in c#. It is supposed to display a 3d Graph of the `function Log(x,y)`. I don't know why but everytime I run it I get the `System.OverflowException` when it begins to draw the graph and the program stops.

How can I prevent it from happening and why does it happen?

```
  private void Draw_Function_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int size = 100;
        double accuracy = 0.09;
        int zoom = 1;
        ver = new double[size, size];
        xtag = new double[size, size];
        ytag = new double[size, size];
        function = Insert_Function.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < 100; p++)
            {
                ver[i, p] = Math.Log(i,p);
                xtag[i, p] = p * accuracy - i * accuracy * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 5);
                ytag[i, p] = ver[i, p] - i * accuracy * Math.Sin(Math.PI / 5);
            }
        }

        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        for (int i = 0; i < ver.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
            for (int p = 1; p < ver.GetLength(1) - 1; p++)
            {
                int y0 = (panel1.Height / 2) - (int)(ytag[i, p] * zoom);
                int x0 = (int)(zoom * xtag[i, p]) + panel1.Width / 2;
                int y1 = (panel1.Height / 2) - (int)(ytag[i + 1, p + 1] * zoom);
                int x1 = (int)(zoom * xtag[i + 1, p + 1]) + panel1.Width / 2;  
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black,
                                 (float)x0,
                                 (float)y0,
                                 (float)x1,
                                 (float)y1);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please paste a text version of your code in the body of the question.

Comment: Look at the line that throws the exception, one of your arithmetic operations or casts produces a result too large for the target type.

Comment: @AlexK. what should I do to make its value fit for the target type?

Comment: the first place I'd look at is the logarithm; log of zero is not defined (edit: mathematically, at least)... and log with a base of zero... what does that mean? i.e. `ver[i, p] = Math.Log(i,p);` when `i` and `p` are both `0`?

Comment: @MarcGravell log of zero is defined as `NegativeInfinity`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.log?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @MarkusDeibel not with base zero, it isn't :)

Comment: Yeah, missed the rather important **base** part.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel of course, if the base wasn't zero - you're right: a `-inf` will be worth looking into when tracking an `OverflowException`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, I changed it so it won't check a log with a base of zero but I still have the same problem

Comment: @Shush well as per the other comments - even without a base of zero, a *log* of zero (with a non-zero base) is -inf; so... that sounds like a great way to cause an overflow exception. Which line of code is throwing?

Comment: It is the kind of code you'd write when you interface to some kind of hardware device or measurement instrument.  It typically comes with a custom DLL that you're supposed to use to read data.  Such DLLs can be troublesome, one thing they can do is modify the floating point processor control word.  Enabling its ability to generate exceptions.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14466004/17034).

Answer (score 0):

I found the following answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9f2b5bba-f725-45c1-9ada-383151267c13/overflow-exception-on-drawline-method-?forum=winforms

> Quote: "Hi, the minimum value allowed for screen coordinate is x = -1073741376 and y = -1073740288, this is the boundary where the desktop surface lies, if you go further, you enter the void, therfore cause an overflow..."

I ran your calculation and besides the fact that it produces NaN and -Infinity values, it also produced very small values like -2147483503. This is the reason why you get the overflow exception.